# WebView and thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, webview

I have application webview. I need add to this program thread which post my php script (runing in background). I have this code:
File: MenuActivity
        package butterfly.menu;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
 WebView mWebView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   startService(new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class));

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // włączenie JS
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false); // blokada ZOOMu



    //mWebView.loadUrl("http://onet.home.pl/"); // strona do wyświetlenia
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MenuClient());
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://onet.home.pl/");
    }

    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://onet.home.pl/");
    }
}
private class MenuClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   mWebView.saveState(outState);
 }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CLEAR || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
        //mWebView.goBack();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://onet.home.pl/");
    }

        else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==   Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://onet.home.pl/onet");
    }
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
} 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
startService(new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class));
super.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent);
} 

    }
```

and OnAlarmReciver:

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new    ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    }
}
```

And it's not running :( Thread not started :(

Who now what i have bad?

Thx for help

Comment: have you enabled the service in the manifest?

Comment: It is really not clear what you're trying to do your `onReceive()` method looks very weird and you usually want it in a `BroadcastReceiver` class also enabled in the manifest file. read this http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html carefully